# Reference for similarity tests for triangles

Tags: geometry, reference-request

For triangles there are the standard similarity tests: AA, SAA, SAS, SSS and SSA (with angle opposite to the longer site).

I am looking for a good reference of those elementary theorems with complete proofs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

[This website](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/SSS.shtml) appears to offer proofs. The page I linked you to has five different proofs for SSS, and I think they must have proofs for everything else you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for nice link! However it would be better to have a book as a reference since I want to cite it. By the way the link is about congruence, my question was about similarity.